# How to set the background colour of elements according to their visibility modifier in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, eclipse-plugin, modifier

I'd like to set the background colour of fields and methods (on the first level) according to their visibility modifier in Eclipse.

For example **private** fields and methods should get a **red** background, while **public** fields and methods get a **green** background:

[image]

Is there a way to configure this in Eclipse?

Comment: A very weird request, but interesting to see if there's a solution for this.

Comment: Could be really helpful,...

Answer (score 1):

To get this sort of a colored background, you need to use **Markers** and **MarkerAnnotationSpecification**. You will find how to use them here: http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/

As for how to find the **private**, **public** fields, you need to use the JDT plugin and the AST parser to parse the Java file and find all the information that you want. I am adding a small code snippet to get you started on this.

```
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST_LEVEL);
        parser.setSource(cmpUnit);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        CompilationUnit astRoot = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        AST ast = astRoot.getAST();

        TypeDeclaration javaType = null;

        Object type = astRoot.types().get(0);
        if (type instanceof TypeDeclaration) {
            javaType =  ((TypeDeclaration) type);
        }


        List<FieldDeclarationInfo> fieldDeclarations = new ArrayList<FieldDeclarationInfo>();

        // Get the field info
        for (FieldDeclaration fieldDeclaration : javaType.getFields()) {
            // From this object you can recover all the information that you want about the fields.
        }
```

Here `cmpUnit` is the `ICompilationUnit` of the Java File.